# Creating a mixed number and letter primary key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb

I have an existing desktop database I am reproducing in mysql server. The current database has a customers table and one of the fields represents zones or areas a company services. The zones are as follows: 1A, 1B, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13,14,15,16,17.

To set this up, to match their existing data set, I have setup a reference table (customer_zones) with the zones linking to the Customers table in a one to many relationship. Each zone can have many customers. Each customer only one zone.

The problem is the "1A" and "1B" zones dont allow me to setup an int primary key on the customer_zones table. I have to use varchar(2) as the primary key. Is this good practice ? or the best solution ?

Comment: Either way, it doesn't sound like much of a 'problem', as such. FWIW, I would have a surrogate, integer PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary key is a clustered index and physical representation of data in a table is because the primary key and searching through numbers is faster than strings.

As per your case below are the approaches.

**Approach A**

If you choose zone id as `varchar(2)` for the Primary key field in a table `customer_zones` then you can reference it to a foreign key field in the `customer`table and your problem would be solved.

**Approach B**

If you will use the primary key as `integer` in table `customer_zone` then to store zones like 1A, 1B, etc you need to have one more field and, on that field, you would require a unique key also avoid data duplication.

It would be better if you follow Approach A as one constraint would be simpler for the same functionality.

Comment: Use Approach A:  `PRIMARY KEY(zone)` as a `VARCHAR(2)`.  The clarity of the data far outweighs the insignificant performance difference in using ints instead of varchars.

Comment: Hi Rick, We both suggested to use approach A but I am unable to understand the reason you have provided. I can see you have a great experience in database and I would really appreciate If you can help me in understanding the same.

Comment: Yes, I have about 2 decades of experience with MySQL/MariaDB, much of it focused on performance and scaling.  18 'zones' makes for a tiny table, but it is good to get into the habit of designing tables optimally.  (See my Answer for addressing your concern.)

Answer (score 0):

I argue in favor of `PRIMARY KEY(zone)` and `VARCHAR(2)`, not a surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

- The number of rows touched by a query is a far bigger factor in performance than the details of the arithmetic / string-comparisions / functions / etc.
- Even with millions of rows, "numbers is faster then strings" is not likely to be noticeable.
- If changing to a surrogate involves an extra `JOIN`, that is extra overhead.
- It is more convenient (when manually looking at the data) to see "1A" and "16", etc.
- I find that 2 times out of 3 that I use a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`, not a "surrogate" (`AUTO_INCREMENT`).  For a many:many mapping table, using a composite PK instead of a surrogate is demonstrably more efficient.

I would suggest in your case this minor optimization:

```
 VARCHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

this avoids the minor overhead of utf8.

I make similar arguments for GUID, UUID, sha1, md5, ip_address, country_code, postal_code, zipcode phone numbers, etc.  For truly fixed length fields, such as 2-letter country_code, use `CHAR(2)` instead of `VARCHAR(2)`.